# Django-filter number lte and gte

Tags: python, django-models

I`m using [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html) to processing submited form.
Queryset in partly consists of annotations.
And for the most of filtered fields lte and gte lookups applied.
Moreover above lookups can fired simultaneously.

```
field_1__lte = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='field_1', lookup_expr='lte')
field_1__gte = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='field_1', lookup_expr='gte')
```

Above field is computing via annotation.

```
 field_1_qs = RelatedObject.objects.filter(MainObject=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-updated_timestamp')
 main_query_set = main_query_set.annotate(field_1:field_1_qs)
```

And there are many similar fields on a dedicated form, like
Min and Max values.
But, somewhy it`s experiencing an troubles with ranges.

If, for example, we set field_1__lte=-1 and field_1__gte = -1,
filter returns empty result.

In the case we set field_1__lte=1 and field_1__gte = 5,
filter will not include in the results low boundary.

In the case we set field_1__lte=-5 and field_1__gte = -3,
filter will not include in the results upper boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it turns out is relative problem with a rounding annotated fields.
In our case, computing the most of annotated fields involving division substruction of two fields by one field. And without casting it resulting all zeros on backend and right values on frontend (while form rendering). So, my solution is using casting.

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, Value, Case, When, IntegerField, FloatField, Transform, ExpressionWrapper
from decimal import Decimal
from django.db.models.functions import Round, Cast
MainQueryset = MainQueryset.annotate( **get_annotation_expression('field_'+str(v), str(v)))

def get_annotation_expression(key, v):
return {
    key:(Case(
            When(column_1=0, then=None),
            default=ExpressionWrapper( (Round( (Cast('column_1', FloatField())-Cast( 'column_'+str(v), FloatField() ) )/Cast('column_1', FloatField() )*Decimal(100))),
                                       output_field=FloatField()
                                      ),    
                                      output_field = IntegerField(),
            )
       ),
}
```

Here we are.
Hope, above will helps somebody one day:=)